# What is this weird spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Today while we're cleaning our storage room I saw this strange looking spider and I'm not even sure if this is a spider, it has two claws folding inward to its mouth and two long weird limbs, it is about 2 inch long and rarely move on its place. Is it poisonous or dangerous to us? What should I do with it?[image]

Comment: Could you give a size estimate for one of the features, and tell us what continent you live on?

Comment: It is about 2 - 2 1/2 inches, it is hiding in our storage room which is so dark and full of mosquitoes here in Leyte, Philippines.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a species from the Arachnid order [Amblypygi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amblypygi) (Tail-less whip scorpions), which are closely related to [Thelyphonida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thelyphonida) (Whip Scorpions). As part of Arachnids, both of these taxa are related to spiders and scorpions, but belong to a separate order.

Even if they look scary, they are harmless to humans, even if they can sometimes bite.

According to [this checklist/site](http://insectoid.info/checklist/amblypygi/philippines/) only three species are listed from the Philippines, so if you want to determine it more closely, it might be useful to start from this list. The list includes: *Sarax brachydactylus*, *Phrynus grayi* and *Charon grayi*.

Here is an example picture (from wikipedia):
[image]

*Charon grayi* (giant whip-spider) from [biotagua.org](https://biotagua.org/2007/05/07/charon-grayi-giant-whip-spider-from-caves/):
[image]